# Access SharePoint intranet application from Sharepoint Designer 2010

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I can not access our intranet portal from SharePoint Designer 2010

1. I enabled anonymous access in IIS for SharePoint web application
2. I enabled user permissions for User Remote Interfaces

It has worked before in the last two weeks

[image]

this web application has below aam
[image]

When I enable verbose logging I find this error:

```
Exception returned from back end service. System.ServiceModel.ServerTooBusyException: The HTTP service located
 at http://spdv01:32843/d8223431896f4032a7e417eecf79819b/MetadataWebService.svc is too busy.  ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.    
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:     
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown
 at [0]:     
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.IMetadataWebServiceApplication.GetServiceSettings(Guid rawPartitionId)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.MetadataWebServiceApplicationProxy.<>c__DisplayClass2f.<ReadApplicationSettings>b__2e(IMetadataWebServiceApplication serviceApplication)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.MetadataWebServiceApplicationProxy.<>c__DisplayClass2c.<RunOnChannel>b__2b()
```

Comment: what the message on Details?

Comment: Hi i also found that in verbose logging 
Error encountered in background cache check System.ServiceModel.ServerTooBusyException: The HTTP service located
 at http://spdv01:32843/d8223431896f4032a7e417eecf79819b/MetadataWebService.svc is too busy.  ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.    
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     -

Comment: in details nothing

Comment: looks like MMS service causing the issue...can you do IIS reset on spdv01?

Comment: yes , i did the IISRESET and restarted this server also?

Comment: now getting the error an error occurred while trying to fetch data from your sharepoint site in sharepoint designer 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I   was able to resolve this issue by web.config file change.
The following entry in the `web.config` file was missing:

```
serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
```

under the `system.serviceModel` tag of the Web Application `web.config`.

I added the entry again and the issue was fixed.

http://mrhodes.net/2010/03/30/sharepoint-designer-2010-the-server-could-not-complete-your-request-the-content-type-of-the-response-is-8/